# Jslider: No number over the ribon

Tags: java, swing

I have used `netbeans` design to set a `jslider` in my `swing` component

Here is the generated code:

```
jSlider1 = new javax.swing.JSlider();
jSlider1.setMaximum(115);
jSlider1.setOpaque(false);
jSlider1.setValueIsAdjusting(true);
```

I would like to have numbers over the ribbon of jslider.So it starts from 0, and the maximum is `115`

**how can i add the numbers over the ribbon?**

Comment: I start by having a look at `JSlider#setPaintLabels`

Comment: You should also have a look at [How to use sliders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html), there's a ready example

Comment: do you need something like this : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AnexampleofJSliderwithdefaultlabels.htm or this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html

Answer (score -2):

You will want to call the [`setPaintLabels`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html#setPaintLabels(boolean)) method on your slider.

Something like:

```
slider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
slider.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
slider.setPaintTicks(true);
slider.setPaintLabels(true);
```

Source: [How to Use Sliders (Oracle)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html)

Answer (score -3):

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;

public class Test {

public void setLabels(){
    Hashtable<Integer, JLabel> labelTable = new Hashtable<Integer, JLabel>();
    JSlider jSlider1 = new JSlider();
    jSlider1.setMaximum(115);
    jSlider1.setOpaque(true);
    jSlider1.setValueIsAdjusting(true);

    for(int i = 0; i <= 115; i++){
        labelTable.put(new Integer(i), new JLabel(new Integer(i).toString()));
    }

    jSlider1.setLabelTable(labelTable);
    jSlider1.setPaintLabels(true);
}
}
```

This code should do the trick. Please try it out.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Comment: Hi @JoeC, sure I will edit this and point the same out to make the solution more helpful to the user.

Thanks